# Integrate current year into label

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to integrate current year into JS label without writing a separate function.

```
Var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear(); // Returns 2018
console.log(year);
```

I mean

```
<label>&copy; copyright YEAR </label>
```

Comment: "into JS label" — what does that mean?

Comment: I mean <label>&copy; copyright YEAR </label>

Comment: Well you've got code to get the year, so all you need is to build the string you want with simple string concatenation right? You have not really described the context for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label>&copy; copyright {new Date().getFullYear()}</label>
```

You could do this but I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.

In your `Render()` method, or if you have a **Stateless Functional Component** in that method itself, **before returning the JSX** you could declare a variable, calculate the year, and assign it to the variable. Then you would use that variable in your JSX. Like this:

```
 const YourComponentName = props => {
     const today = new Date();
     const year = today.getFullYear();
     return (
          <label>&copy; copyright {year}</label>
      );
 };
```

This way, your code is much more readable.

Comment: This is the best method provided. All works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The shortest possible would be something like this!

```
<label>&copy; copyright <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script></label>
```